# Why did my method of writing list items to a .txt file not work?

Tags: python

I've written a short program will take an input file, remove punctuation, sort the contents by number of occurrences per word and then write the 100 most common results to an output file.

I had some trouble on the last part (writing the results to an output file), and though I've fixed it, I don't know what the problem was.

The full code looks like so:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
import sys
import string

wordList = []

#this file contains text from a number of reviews
file1 = open('reviewfile', 'r+')
reviewWords = file1.read().lower()

#this file contains a list of the 1000 most common English words
file2 = open('commonwordsfile', 'r')
commonWords = file2.read().lower()

#remove punctuation
for char in string.punctuation:
    reviewWords = reviewWords.replace(char, " ")

#create a list of individual words from file1
splitWords = reviewWords.split()
for w in splitWords:
    if w not in commonWords and len(w)>2:
        wordList.append(w)

#sort the resulting list by length
wordList = sorted(wordList, key=len)

#return a list containing the 100
#most common words and number of occurrences
words_to_count = (word for word in wordList)
c = Counter(words_to_count)
commonHundred = c.most_common(100)

#create new file for results and write
#the 100 most common words to it
fileHandle = open("outcome", 'w' )  
for listItem in commonHundred:  
    fileHandle.write (str(listItem) + "\n")
fileHandle.close()
```

I previously had this following code snippet attempting to write the 100 most common terms to a .txt file, but it didn't work. Can anyone explain why not?

```
makeFile = open("outputfile", "w")
for item in CommonHundred:
    makeFile.write("[0]\n".format(item))
makeFile.close()
```

Comment: _What_ didn't work? What specifically is the problem?

Comment: The code snippet I've put at the end. I originally tried this method of writing to the output file but it just produced an empty file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those should be curly braces, like:

```
makefile.write("{0}\n".format(item))
```

Run this and see what happens:

```
a = "[0]".format("test")
print(a)

b = "{0}".format("test")
print(b)
```

Then go search for "Format String Syntax" here if you'd like to know more: http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html.

Comment: Right you are, Tim! It didn't even register. I think I need better glasses or to increase the font size on my computer. Thank you!

Comment: You don't even need 0 - just curly brackets will do

Comment: This is true. For whatever reasons I like the aesthetic of always placing integers in my format strings, but it's probably "better" to go with the more succinct form.